# Row Counter Only Counting? Top Row

Tags: excel, vba, rowcount

My code is supposed to select all of the items in A-H from the top of the sheet to the bottom most row containing text in the J column. However, now all it does is select the top row. This code has worked fine elsewhere for other purposes, but when I run it here it only selects the top row.

Here is the code and what it currently does. The commented out bit does the same when it is ran in the place of the other `finalrow =`statement.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindRow()

Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
Dim finalrow As Integer

Set reportsheet = Sheet29

Sheet29.Activate
'finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
finalrow = Range("J1048576").End(xlUp).Row


    If Not IsEmpty(Sheet29.Range("B2").Value) Then
         Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(finalrow, 8)).Select

    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

This is the excerpt of code with a row counter that works.

```
datasheet.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

''loop through the rows to find the matching records
For i = 1 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = item_code Then ''if the name in H1 matches the search name then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9)).Copy ''copy columns 1 to 9 (A to I)
        reportsheet.Select ''go to the report sheet
        Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False ''find the first blank and paste info there
        datasheet.Select ''go back to the data sheet and continue searching
        End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindRow()

    ' always use Longs over Integers
    Dim finalrow As Long: finalrow = 1

    ' you might not need this line tbh
    Sheet29.Activate

    With Sheet29

        ' custom find last row
        Do While True
            finalrow = finalrow + 1
            If Len(CStr(.Range("J" & finalrow).Value)) = 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        ' Len() is sometimes better then IsEmpty()
        If Len(CStr(.Range("B2").Value)) > 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells((finalrow - 1), 8)).Select
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. It still does the same thing. At this point, however, I don't believe there was/ is a problem with this portion of code. I also just put random text in the K column beside of where there is text in the J column, switched the "J" for "K" in finalrow= and it worked fine. The difference is that column J is full of formulas from top to bottom. Does the row count look for formulas as well? If it does, is there a way around it?

Comment: @jacob_m what formula is column J filled with?

Comment: something like "=IF(B2=I2,"","TON") " except the numbers correspond to their row. sorry I'm away from my computer but I believe that's it

Comment: @jacob_m just updated my answer and added code to find the last row in column J using a loop, also initiated `finalrow = 1` at top